# How to properly generate a sequence of numbers between 0 and 1 in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get a sequence of evenly spaced numbers between 0 and 1 in R. I am, however, running into an issue.

```
test <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
test
test[2] == .1
test[4] == .3
```

Why does the first test of equality evaluate to `TRUE` while the second one evaluates to `FALSE`? Because I am later using the `subset` function within a `Shiny` app, I need `test[4]` to be exactly .3 for subsetting to work properly.

How can I do this? Also, can someone tell me why what I am doing is wrong, or is it a bug? The following works as expected:

```
test <- seq(0, 10, by = 1)
test
test[2] == 1
test[4] == 3
```

Comment: @ekstroem is correct, this is a floating point issue.

Comment: thanks. so the correct way is to use `all.equal` instead.